# AngularJS display different states of an app after a promise call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question: Imagine, we have two states on an app

1. Dialog for creating a team for competition with a actual button
2. Actual form for creating a team with all inputs and stuff.

App checks, using factory promise, if user already created a team and throw an "edit screen” instead of creating button.

I’m switching states by using ng-hide and ng-show with a $scope var being assigned after successful promise. It works fine but I have a flash of “Create new team” screen before promise being resolved. Which is of course not okey.

```
<div class="teamtable">

<div ng-show="teamAdded">
   <input type="text" name="teamname"/>
   <input type="text" name="playername"/>
   <button ng-click="saveTeam()">Save</button>
</div>
<div ng-hide="teamAdded">
    <div class="team__hint">
      Create your team
      <button id="button" ng-click="createTeam()">Create team</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

teamAdded sets true after successful promise.

So how can I make a check or wait until a promise will be resolved or use condition or whatever to display only one screen at a time? Thanks

Comment: can you provide a bit more code? or even sample plunkr ?

Comment: are you using ui-router ? If so you can add a resolve parametr to your state, the ui-router will wait for the resolve to complete before displaying anything. This is true for ngRoute too.

Comment: @Walfrat, I'm using ui-router in other parts of my app, but that a good idea too. I will consider using ui-router for this either way!

Comment: if you use a modal angular library, it may have a resolve parameter too, check the documentation though i'm not sure if the edit screen is in the modal or not there.

Comment: @Walfrat thanks! It's not in the modal - it just re-render page.

Comment: @Walfrat as I'm checking documentation for ui-router it's says that it can provide controller with a data before it's loaded, which is nice. Thanks for putting me in right direction!

Comment: yes that the resolve parameter of the state :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create loading flag to indicate is data loaded or not.

In controller:

```
....
$scope.isLoaded = false;
yourResource.fetchData().then(function() {
    $scope.isLoaded = true;
    //Do some stuff
}
```

And in template you could wrap all your stuff to

```
<div ng-if="isLoaded ">...</div>
```

And create alternative div:

```
<div ng-if="!isLoaded ">Loading....</div>
```

Comment: I will try this and respond back to you! Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your time! It's not really that I'm looking for because that way second state of an app is just a temporarily loading screen, but I need an actual working UI depending on promise result.

Looks like it's more of a job for ui-route, but thanks for your time!

Comment: But in your case displayed view depends on promise result, so it is bad idea to show some actual view before promise resolved. Anyway, you are welcome :)

Comment: Maybe, you're right, actually. It's hard to figure out sometimes, you know :). I can put that loading thing before any view and then do whatever.

Comment: Actually don't see any diffrence between my soultion and @Julian's. Both of them hide both views till promise is resolved, but in my case there will no dummy emty screen while data is loading. After promise resolved, in  //Do some stuff block you can insert your logic and set value to teamAdded depend on fetched data.

Comment: I'm not trying to offend, I'm trying to figure out :) I will change picked answer if so :)

Comment: It's okay, i take no offence, i'm just explain :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just hide both until you know which one to show.

```
<div class="teamtable">

<div ng-if="showCreateMask">
   <input type="text" name="teamname"/>
   <input type="text" name="playername"/>
   <button ng-click="saveTeam()">Save</button>
</div>
<div ng-if="showEditMask">
    <div class="team__hint">
      Create your team
      <button id="button" ng-click="createTeam()">Create team</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

in your js you could do something like:

```
showCreateMask = false;
showEditMask = false;

promise.success(function(teamAdded) {
   showCreateMask = !teamAdded;
   showEditMask = teamAdded;
});
```

This way it would show the respective mask when the promise is done. Before that it would show nothing.

Regards

Comment: I will try this and respond back to you! Thanks!

Comment: your solution is answering my question, thanks for that! But as I investigate further I understand that I need to look at routing thing. Thanks!

Comment: @Keeprock - when you have a look at routing: I would recommend you have a look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router since the standard routing of angular is not as powerful. Hopefully this can help you to prevent some trouble you might run into.